# Select for Update behavior

Tags: multithreading, postgresql, concurrency, thread-safety, select-for-update

I have I good understanding of what happens in regard to the update of a row when SELECT FOR UPDATE is used and another SELECT/UPDATE takes place. But what happens when two requests take place with SELECT FOR UPDATE.

For example:

1. Thread A **starts a transaction** and does a a SELECT FOR UPDATE on a row and retrieves some info and begins an HTTP request that takes time. After the call has returned **the transaction is committed and the session is closed**.
2. Thread B, as A waits for the request, **starts a new transaction** and does a SELECT FOR UPDATE on the same row. Will it retrieve the information and proceed with the HTTP request on its on or will it wait for thread A to commit/do the update and then retrieve the data from the row.

I do not care what will happen once the request returns and the time to update the table comes. The second that goes for the update will either throw or update the last possible data on the row.

But will the actual HTTP request be done by both of them? In other words can in this scenario SELECT FOR UPDATE be used (abused) as a thread synchronization mechanism?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are mixing up layers. PostgreSQL doesn't do HTTP. `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` has nothing to do with HTTP.

Here's how it works:

- Session 1 does `BEGIN`
- Session 2 does `BEGIN`
- Session 1 does `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` and gets one or more rows
- Session 2 does `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` and matches one of the same rows, so it *blocks*, not returning anything, until...
- Session 1 does a `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK`
- Session 2 gets the results from the earlier `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`

In other words, lock duration is controlled by transaction boundaries. Where the transaction boundaries lie depends on your application and framework, stuff way above the database layer that you haven't identified in any way.

(Also, this has nothing to do with threads).

Comment: Thank you Craig. Yes I know that threads and Http are not relevant to PostgreSQL. Maybe I did not express myself properly. However, you answered my question I think. Session 2 block its execution and does not proceed until Session 1 has commit. So it will not move forward to the HTTP call that exists after the SELECT FOR UPDATE until session 1 has committed the changes. Am I correct?

Comment: @idipous As I said, it is not possible to answer that because I don't know what framework you are using, how it manages transactions, etc. It depends on when the application commits. That is all. So you have to figure out when the application will commit. It sounds, per your edits, like the transaction is held open throughout the HTTP exchange with the client, in which case yes, it'll prevent session B from continuing until session A has returned. It all depends on when you commit.

Comment: I edited my question to clear up the transaction begin and commit points.